# Why does the frequency in fft plot of the baseband modulated signal isn't changing at the receiver

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-spectrum, filter-design, modulation

I have designed a transceiver system for cellular frequencies(800MHz). On the receiver side, I have converted the band signal to baseband signal through digital mixing. I have added the Inphase and Q phase signal to generate the qpsk signal. But when I plot the fft of the signal, then the frequency in fft plot is not changing in spite of changing the carrier frequency at the transmitter.

[image: Signal+Noise, SNR =-10dB, FFT of the same]

```
ws = (0.28*pi);%input('stopband edge frequency in radians,ws1 = ');
0.63*pi = 16.25MHz || 18.2MH = 177  30%  40% = 0.28, 0.2 wp = (0.2*pi);%input(' passband edge frequency in radians,wp1 = '); cut off frq. = 0.485*pi = 12.5MHz(old), fs =51.5MHz 13MH= 0.126

tr_width = ((18.2-13)/130);

n = ceil((6.6*pi)/tr_width); %Hamming Window is used if (mod(n,2)== 0)
    N = n+1; else
    N = n; end

wc1 = (ws+wp)/2;

if N<=0
    error(' N should be greater than zero');  end

if wp > pi
    error('cut off frequecnies should be less than pi'); end

hd = zeros(1,N); % N =285 alpha = (N-1)/2; %142


 k = 0 : 1 : ((N-1)); % length = 142  n2 = k-((N-1)/2);
     for temp = 1:N
      n1=temp-((N-1)/2)-1;
      if(n1~=0)
            hd(temp) = sin(wc1*n1)./(pi*n1); % Nagoor Kani  
      else
          hd(temp) = (wc1/pi);
      end   end

 k = 1 : 1 : N;  
    w_ham(k) = 0.54-0.46*cos(2*pi*(k-1)/(N-1));   hn = (hd.*w_ham);

w1 = 0 : (pi/(17)) : pi;
    hw1 = hd_0 * exp (-1i*w1*alpha);
    hw2 = 0; for m = 1 : 1 : alpha
    hw3 = hn(m) * (( exp(1i*w1*(1-m))) + (exp(-1i*w1*(1-m+2*alpha)))); % generation of complex equivalent
    hw2 = hw2 + hw3; end

hw = hw2 + hw1;   h_mag = abs(hw);

figure(9); stem (n2,hd,'b') title('impulse response of ideal low Pass Filter'); xlabel('Discrete time n'); ylabel('hd(n)'); grid on; hold on;

len= length(w_ham);

L1_r =0:1:len-1; [mag,w] = freqz(hn,1,length(hn));    % [H,W] = FREQZ(B,A,N) returns the N-point db = 20*log10(mag);     % complex frequency response vector H and the  pha = angle(mag);            % N-point frequency vector W in radians/sample of the filter  
                              low_inp = filter(hw,1,inph_r);           % Filtering the input signal low_qp = filter(hw,1,qph_r);
```

Comment: In such questions, please add more details such as the code you are using (as a bug is certainly possible) and the plots you are mentioning.

Comment: yeah, this sounds like a bug

Comment: @MarcusMüller,  I have attached the plot. please do look into it. The code is quite lengthy, do you want to have a look at it

Comment: @PradyothShandilya, The low pass filter pass band is 13MHz , so the frequency shown is near to it and is fixed

Comment: @Rajee yes, that plot suggests something is buggy, as said.

Comment: @MarcusMuller,  I have put up the code of LPF for complex signals. I feel this is giving me error. could you let me know whats the error